# didDiscoverPeripheral not called on ios in background when searching for HM-11

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

I built out my application using the Apple BLTE Transfer example https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html and modified it to try to connect to my HM-11 chip that is running as an iBeacon.

In the foreground, the application is capable of discovering the HM-11:

```
2017-02-26 17:46:26.872 BTLE Transfer[831:436577] Scanning started
2017-02-26 17:46:26.896 BTLE Transfer[831:436577] Discovered MY_DEVICE at -46
2017-02-26 17:46:26.896 BTLE Transfer[831:436577] Connecting to peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x17d52de0, identifier = 8ADFF3DC-A902-3CE6-CDEB-168E67594AF7, name = MY_DEVICE, state = disconnected>
2017-02-26 17:46:27.202 BTLE Transfer[831:436577] Peripheral Connected
2017-02-26 17:46:27.203 BTLE Transfer[831:436577] Scanning stopped
2017-02-26 17:46:27.501 BTLE Transfer[831:436577] Discovered service: <CBService: 0x17e9d830, isPrimary = YES, UUID = FFE0>
2017-02-26 17:46:27.801 BTLE Transfer[831:436577] Notification began on <CBCharacteristic: 0x17e3a630, UUID = FFE1, properties = 0x16, value = (null), notifying = YES>
```

However, in the background nothing occurs past:

```
2017-02-26 17:46:31.179 BTLE Transfer[831:436577] Scanning started
```

Here is how scanning is being set up:

```
/** centralManagerDidUpdateState is a required protocol method.
 *  Usually, you'd check for other states to make sure the current device supports LE, is powered on, etc.
 *  In this instance, we're just using it to wait for CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn, which indicates
 *  the Central is ready to be used.
 */
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        // In a real app, you'd deal with all the states correctly
        return;
    }

    // The state must be CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn...

    // ... so start scanning
    [self scan];

}


/** Scan for peripherals - specifically for our service's 128bit CBUUID
 */
- (void)scan
{
//    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil
//                                                options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @NO }];
    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]]
                                                options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @NO }];

    NSLog(@"Scanning started");
}
```

I am making sure to only start scanning once I am in the `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn` state.

And when scanning I am specifying the service UUID to look for as `FFE0`.

This is defined in `TransferService.h` as:

```
#define TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID @"FFE0"
#define TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID @"FFE1"
```

And I realize that duplicate keys won't be scanned for in the background mode. So I have tested the case where the HM-11 is turned off when scanning starts, the app is put into the background, and then the HM-11 is turned on. I think that that should ensure that the device hasn't been "discovered" already by app so it wouldn't appear as a duplicate key. But even in this case, the `didDiscoverPeripheral` delegate is only called after the app is returned to the foreground.

I am initializing the `CBCentralManager` like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Start up the CBCentralManager
    _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    // And somewhere to store the incoming data
    _data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}
```

I am also including the necessary permissions for my application with the following code in `Supporting Files\BTLE Transfer-Info.plist`:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>bluetooth-central</string>
    <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
</array>
```

In the `Capabilities` tab for the app both `Uses Bluetooth LE accessories` and `Acts as a Bluetooth LE accessory` are checked. I don't need to have `Acts as a Bluetooth LE accessory` but I was just trying different things to see if I could get it working.

Any ideas as to why I'm not discovering this peripheral when the app is running in the background?

Comment: How long are you waiting for the peripheral to be discovered in the background?

Comment: I've waited up to 30 seconds. The HM-11 is broadcasting at an interval of 100ms.

Comment: Even leaving it scanning a solid four minutes doesn't result in any discovering. But then as soon as I bring it into the foreground it works again.

Comment: Is your app just in the background, or is the device locked too?

Comment: It's just that the app is in the background. It's not locked.

Comment: I am doing some testing with a different peripheral (but that shouldn't matter).  If I power on the peripheral within a few seconds of the app going into the background, the peripheral is seen pretty quickly.  If I wait about 3 minutes before powering on then the peripheral isn't seen.  If I run another app in the foreground that is scanning (LightBlue) then my test app sees the peripheral straight away.

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion. Any idea why running LightBlue in the foreground would cause my app to then discover the peripheral properly? My app would still be in the background in that case. It doesn't work with other apps so it probably has to do with the fact that LightBlue is doing a scan right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136708/discussion-between-davis-and-paulw11).